# Dynamic Columns in a UITableView with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

In my iPad app, I will have a `UITableView` that is being displayed in a popover.  I have multiple values that I want to display, so I made a custom `UITableViewCell` with several labels, to simulate many "columns" in the table.  What I want to do is make sure all of my "columns" will be lined up.

The catch is, I can't hardcode the widths of my columns, because I am dynamically populating the data from an XML webservice - so I don't know how wide they need to be until I've made that call and received the data.

My thoughts are to loop through the data (once I get it), and use the `sizeWithAttributs:` method of `NSString` to get the maximum width for each of my columns.  I will then send that width to my custom cell, so the cell can use it in its `layoutSubviews` method.  The problem is, I'm trying to do all this with `NSLayoutConstraints`, and in all the examples I've seen, the any sizes in `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` are always hardcoded - I won't know what my sizes are until runtime.  My idea is to do something like

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel1,myLabel2)
NSArray *myConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myLabel1(%d)]-[myLabel2(%d)]",myWidth1,myWidth2 options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:myDictionary];
```

But this causes a build error.  Is it possible to dynamically provide a size to `constraintsWithVisualFormat` at runtime, instead of hardcoding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way of doing this is to use the `metrics` parameter:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myLabel1,myLabel2)
NSArray *myConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint 
          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[myLabel1(lbl1w)]-[myLabel2(lbl2w)]" 
                              options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline 
                              metrics:@{@"lbl1w": @(myWidth1),
                                        @"lbl2w": @(myWidth2) } 
                                views:myDictionary];
```

This basically allows you to provided a dictionary mapping names to numeric values for use anywhere in the visual format string. The values need to be `NSNumber` instances, which can be easily constructed from C numeric variables using the `@(aVariable)` construct introduced last year.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why this way is recommended, over using my way?  Using the metrics doesn't seem any simpler to me (I would argue it is even more complicated).  Additionally, I don't recall seeing a `metrics` dictionary used to link a value to a temporary variable, just to be used in another parameter, but I have seen a ton of instances of passing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."]` instead of just `@"..."` when a `NSString` is requested as the input type.  I guess I'm just a little confused why constraints should be done any differently.

Comment: It's not at all that using string format isn't recommended *per se*. Since the Auto Layout's visual format parser is going to do the string parsing work anyway, you might as well tell it to substitute some names for their numeric values. Your way makes string parsing happen twice. Also, actual names are always going to be more readable than a bunch of `%d`. Finally, if you were to reuse the same value multiple times, this way is going to prove itself handy.

Comment: Also, it's cleaner if you were to either reuse a visual format with different widths or margins, or reuse a set of widths/margins across visual formats. It's just worth wrapping your head around!

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this up, I had a flash of non-stupidity that motivated me to look at what you are actually supposed to pass as the first argument to `constraintsWithVisualFormat`, and sure enough, it's just looking for an `NSString`.  So the solution is to simply break the string out in front:

```
NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-[myLabel1(%d)]-[myLabel2(%d)]",myWidth1,myWidth2];
```

and then pass it in:

```
NSArray *myConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formattedString options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:myDictionary];
```

I haven't tested this yet (there's still a lot of stuff I have to code for doing the looping through the data and all that), but it should work.  As I said, all the examples I saw hardcoded the sizes, so I figured I'd post this in case anyone else comes looking for how to do it, or in case I forget later =).